# wrong data fetching with +1 in angularjs $scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am creating a web app in which i need to see data of different days depends on button click

i have 3 buttons

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-model="today" ng-click="prevbutton()">previous</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-model="today" ng-click="tod()">Today</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-model="nextbuttons" ng-click="nextbutton()">Next</button>
```

> previous button will show the previous days data depends on how many
>   time it is clicked(if clicked 1 time it will show yesterday's data if
>   twice then to days before's data) it is working fine
>
> now button will show today's data and it is also working fine

next button will be showing data of upcoming dates, now the prob is with next button if i click next it will show me data of tomorrow and if i once again click next it will jump to the date which is coming 10 days after tomorrow(`that is if i click once it will show me data of 8th if i click twice it is jumping to 18`) but once i clicked on previous button then i clicked on next button it will show me data properly that is (`that is if i click once it will show me data of 8th and if i clicked twice it will show me data of 9th`)

this is my js

```
$scope.tod = function () {
            $scope.button = "0";
            $http.get('/Models/welcome.asmx/welcomegrid', {
                params:
                {
                    log: 'admin',
                    pm: 'admin',
                    button: $scope.button
                }
            })
       .then(function (response) {
           $scope.welcometable = response.data.welcome;
           console.log(response.data.welcome);
       })
        }

        $scope.nextbutton = function () {
            $scope.button = $scope.button + 01;
            $http.get('/Models/welcome.asmx/welcomegrid', {
                params:
                {
                    log: 'admin',
                    pm: 'admin',
                    button: $scope.button
                }
            })
       .then(function (response) {
           $scope.welcometable = response.data.welcome;
           console.log(response.data.welcome);
       })
        }

        $scope.prevbutton = function () {
            $scope.button = $scope.button - 1;
            $http.get('/Models/welcome.asmx/welcomegrid', {
                params:
                {
                    log: 'admin',
                    pm: 'admin',
                    button: $scope.button
                }
            })
       .then(function (response) {
           $scope.welcometable = response.data.welcome;
           console.log(response.data.welcome);
       })
        }
```

needed your help

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Your problem is thing that you don't know how to implement `click it twice and move + 11 days` ?

Comment: How is the backend receiving the button data? I think the problem is in your backend...

Comment: @GustavoGabriel this js file is my backend

Comment: if i click on the button ` $scope.nextbutton = function () {` this function will be run and increment the value of $scope.button by 1

Comment: You are making a http get call to get the data, the js is not the backend. The $scope.next_button is only incrementing a int value, this value you are sending to the backend... and with this value you know when to get next or previous date...